# Cannot build a project using maven archetype installed locally

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, aem-project-archetype

I am trying to test an unreleased version of a maven Archetype (24-SNAPSHOT) on my local/computer.

Archetype sources:

- Using this project https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype , downloaded the sources
- Ran this command `mvn install`

  - Also tried `mvn install archetype:update-local-catalog`
- The build was successful and i can also see the jar files copied to `.m2` directory.

```
[INFO] Installing /Users/s/Projects/aem-project-archetype-master/target/aem-project-archetype-24-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/s/.m2/repository/com/adobe/aem/aem-project-archetype/24-SNAPSHOT/aem-project-archetype-24-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/s/Projects/research/AEM/aem-project-archetype-master/pom.xml to /Users/s/.m2/repository/com/adobe/aem/aem-project-archetype/24-SNAPSHOT/aem-project-archetype-24-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Can see it when using `mvn archetype:crawl`

```
...
[INFO] Scanning /Users/s/.m2/repository/com/adobe/aem/aem-project-archetype/24-SNAPSHOT/aem-project-archetype-24-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]  Archetype [com.adobe.aem:aem-project-archetype:24-SNAPSHOT] defined by repository path
```

When trying to create a new project but wanted to use the above built local archetype file.. using below command (with or without `-DarchetypeCatalog=local`)

`mvn -B archetype:generate -D archetypeGroupId=com.adobe.granite.archetypes -D archetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype -D archetypeVersion=24-SNAPSHOT -D aemVersion=6.5.0 -D appTitle="Demo Site" -D appId="demosite" -D groupId="com.demo.site" -D frontendModule=general -D includeExamples=y -DarchetypeCatalog=local`

Shows this error message with "Build Failure":

```
...
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository.
[WARNING] Add a repository with id 'archetype' in your settings.xml if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
[WARNING] The POM for com.adobe.granite.archetypes:aem-project-archetype:jar:24-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

I have not added anything to `.m2/settings.xml`. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

After carefully looking at the commands being used, found the issue and solution.

The public path for the Archetype is: **com.adobe.granite.archetypes** by looking at the suggested command to use for published archetypes:

`-D archetypeGroupId=com.adobe.granite.archetypes`

while a local build is adding the Archetype in **/.m2/repository/com/adobe/aem/** and not at **/.m2/repository/com/adobe/granite/archetypes**

The scan `mvn archetype:crawl` also shows the path as:

`[INFO] Scanning /Users/s/.m2/repository/com/adobe/aem/aem-project-archetype/24-SNAPSHOT/aem-project-archetype-24-SNAPSHOT.jar`

So a change in the command using (`-D archetypeGroupId=com.adobe.aem`) helped solve the issue:

Complete command:

`mvn -B archetype:generate -D archetypeGroupId=com.adobe.aem -D archetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype -D archetypeVersion=24-SNAPSHOT -D aemVersion=6.5.0 -D appTitle="Demo Site" -D appId="demosite" -D groupId="com.demo.site" -D frontendModule=general -D includeExamples=y -DarchetypeCatalog=local`